# Cannot resolve symbol in (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.xxx)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I want to create a food menu using RecycleView by connecting to firebase, I have declared recycler_menu as variable, but when i type     **`recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);`** there are error showing cannot resolve symbol     R.id.recycler_menu. Need help on solving this error.I have added         **`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'`** support library but still unable to solve this error.

**Home.java**

```
package com.example.liew.idelivery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.Common.Common;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.Model.Category;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference category;
TextView txtFullName;
RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Init Firebase

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    category = database.getReference("Category");
    TextView txtFullName;


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //set name for user

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
    txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

    // Load menu

    recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadMenu();

}

private void loadMenu() {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {

            viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this,""+clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MenuViewHolder.java**

```
package com.example.liew.idelivery.ViewHolder;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.liew.idelivery.R;

public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {

public TextView txtMenuName;
public ImageView imageView;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MenuViewHolder(View itemView){
    super(itemView);

    txtMenuName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
    imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){

    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}
}
```

**menu_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
app:cardElevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_name"
        android:text="Name of Menu"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#4f0e0d0e"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? 
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
app:cardElevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_name"
        android:text="Name of Menu"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#4f0e0d0e"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

content_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Home"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For those who willing to help me but not really understand my code, can give me your email address.I will email you my full code to get rid of this error.

Comment: Add activity_home xml code also

Comment: post your activity_home.xml

Comment: added activity_home.xml

Comment: i found out my error. It is inside the content_home.xml. But how should i modify it so that there are no error ?

Comment: My error is inside content_home.xml. By the way, how should i modify it?nexpected text found in layout file: "android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"  android:scrollbars="vertical"  android:layout_width="..." less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Layout resource files should only contain elements and attributes. Any XML text content found in the file is likely accidental (and potentially dangerous if the text resembles XML and the developer believes the text to be functional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `content_home.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

What is wrong with your code is the `>` character is placed in the wrong position, your original code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Thanks dude for helping. I did not realize i lack a > in the content_home.xml. Such hilarious.

Comment: @LiewSyetChau please be so kind and fair to mark this post as answer. Tam will get reputation for his help.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById searches for the ID "recycler_menu" in the xml-files.

This error appears if there is no ID like this in your xml-files.

As I see it right this ID isn't implemented in your XML-File. Maybe you have some more xml-Files where it is implemented? Please show the xml file where this ID is implemented

Comment: i found out my error. It is inside the content_home.xml. But how should i modify it so that there are no error ?

Comment: unexpected text found in layout file: "android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"  android:scrollbars="vertical"  android:layout_width="..." less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Layout resource files should only contain elements and attributes. Any XML text content found in the file is likely accidental (and potentially dangerous if the text resembles XML and the developer believes the text to be functional)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to claim

```
     recycler_menu =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
```

You should create a xml file like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`

Comment: unexpected text found in layout file: "android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"  android:scrollbars="vertical"  android:layout_width="..." less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Layout resource files should only contain elements and attributes. Any XML text content found in the file is likely accidental (and potentially dangerous if the text resembles XML and the developer believes the text to be functional)

Comment: i found out my error. It is inside the content_home.xml. But how should i modify it so that there are no error ?

Answer (score 0):

Code for getting reference is perfectly alright

```
 recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
```

Go to XML of activity_home and re-confirm that recyclerview has id with name

> recycler_menu

like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

for more help kindly send XML of activity_home

Comment: unexpected text found in layout file: "android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"  android:scrollbars="vertical"  android:layout_width="..." less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Layout resource files should only contain elements and attributes. Any XML text content found in the file is likely accidental (and potentially dangerous if the text resembles XML and the developer believes the text to be functional)

Comment: i found out my error. It is inside the content_home.xml. But how should i modify it so that there are no error ?